# Orator ORM model Create method invalid SQL

Tags: python, orm, relational-database

I have a database I created with a migration. One of my tables looks like this

```
def create_customer_table(self):
        with self.schema.create("customer") as table:
        table.char("name",120).unique()
        table.integer("transmitting_hours").default(24) #how many hours after transmission vehicle is considered transmitting
        table.boolean("is_tpms").default(False)
        table.boolean("is_dor").default(False)
        table.boolean("is_otr").default(False)
        table.boolean("is_track_and_trace").default(False)
        table.char("contact_person",25)
        table.char("created_by",25)
        table.enum("temperature_unit",TEMP_UNITS)
        table.enum("pressure_unit",PRESSURE_UNITS)
        table.enum("distance_unit",DISTANCE_UNITS)
        table.char("time_zone",25)
        table.char("language",2)
        table.timestamps()
```

I have a very simplistic ORM model on top

```
class Customer(Model):
     __table__ = "customer"
     __timestamps__ = False
     __primary_key__ = "name"
     __fillable__ = ['*']
```

I then try to do a basic insert with the following code

```
def add_sample_customer():
    sample_customer = {}
    sample_customer["name"] = "customer_2"
    sample_customer["contact_person"] = "Abradolf"
    sample_customer["created_by"] = "Frodo"
    sample_customer["time_zone"] = "GMT-5"
    sample_customer["language"] = "EN"
    sample_customer["temperature_unit"] = "FAHRENHEIT"
    sample_customer["pressure_unit"] = "PSI"
    sample_customer["distance_unit"] = "MI"
    customer_model = Customer.create(_attributes = sample_customer)
```

The exception I get from this code looks like

```
orator.exceptions.query.QueryException: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "customer" () VALUES () RETURNING "name"                               
(SQL: INSERT INTO "customer" () VALUES () RETURNING "name" ([]))
```

it looks like orator just isn't filling in the cols and vals here. I have also tried it with a few different syntactic ways of dropping the dict in there, using **sample_customer and also just putting the dict in directly and none of them work, all with the same exception. I started debugging by printing stuff out of the orator libraries but haven't gotten anywhere yet.

my inserts work if I do the model attribute assignment individually and use the model.save() method like this

```
def add_sample_customer():
    sample_customer = {}
    sample_customer["name"] = "customer_2"
    sample_customer["contact_person"] = "Abradolf"
    sample_customer["created_by"] = "Frodo"
    sample_customer["time_zone"] = "GMT-5"
    sample_customer["language"] = "EN"
    sample_customer["temperature_unit"] = "FAHRENHEIT"
    sample_customer["pressure_unit"] = "PSI"
    sample_customer["distance_unit"] = "MI"
    customer_model = Customer()
    for k,v in sample_customer.items():
        setattr(customer_model,k,v)
    customer_model.save()
```

Does anyone understand why the model.create() syntax fails?

Comment: Does `customer_model = Customer.create(**sample_customer)` work?

Comment: That gives the same exception as described above with the empty insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the answer would be:
Simply passing the dictionary instead of using keyword notation with attributes:

```
Customer.create(sample_customer)
```

or

```
Customer.create(attribute=value,attribute2=value2,..etc)
```

Which are the valid notations